# Convert array of objects into an array but in a different format.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array of objects as shown below. I did a console.log(values); and got below result

```
["15- S&P", "us- ex US", "al- ex CL"]

0:"15- S&P"
1:"us- ex US"
2:"al- ex CL"
length:3
__proto__:Array(0)
```

I want the output in a array with values as follows.

```
[S&P, ex US, ex CL]
```

All values before the '-' are eliminated and values after '-' are taken and put in an array. for e.g. '15- S&P' is changed to 'S&P'. Can anyone please let me know how to achieve this.

Comment: `["15- S&P", "us- ex US", "al- ex CL"].map(s => s.match(/- (.*)/).pop())`

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Array#map` and `String#split` to return just the text after `-` sign from every element.

```js
var arr = ["15- S&P", "us- ex US", "al- ex CL"],
    res = arr.map(v => v.split("- ")[1]);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also try this;

```js
var arr = ["15- S&P", "us- ex US", "al- ex CL"],
    res = arr.map(s => s.replace(/\w+-\s*([\w&\s]+)/,"$1"));
console.log(res);
```